# Producing a pdf with internal anchor links using dompdf

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf

I am using dompdf to collate a load of existing HTML pages. A lot of these pages have anchor links in them that I would like to preserve. When I collate these articles the pdf collates very nicely but the anchors links don't work. The text is underlined like a link but on clicking it you don't go anywhere.

I have some test HTML that I am using to try out anchor links. Such as:

```
$content .= '<div style="page-break-after: always;"><a href="#link">blah</a></div> 
             <div><a id="blah">link location</a></div>';
```

and also I have tried using name instead of id, based on this forum post - http://www.dashinteractive.net/dompdf/index.php?v=1530231. Such as:

```
$content .= '<div style="page-break-after: always;"><a href="#link">blah</a></div> 
             <div><a name="blah">link location</a></div>';
```

Of course neither of these are working as I would expect.

I can't find much on the internet about how dompdf handles internal links. Apart from this page http://webresourcesdepot.com/html-to-pdf-rendering-engine-dompdf/ that says it can handle links and anchors. Not sure how reliable it is...

How do you put internal anchor links in pdfs using dompdf please? Can it do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dompdf up through 0.6.2 should work so long as you use the `<a name="blah">...</a>` format. The only problem in that release is that if the A tag is empty it will be removed before the link is rendered.

Your second sample should be fine, though maybe just as part of typing up the question the actual anchor reference is incorrect. The following should work:

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;"><a href="#blah">blah</a></div>
<div><a name="blah">link location</a></div>
```

The current beta for 0.7.0 [has a bug](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1147) that mangles the anchor resulting in a mis-interpreted link type. That issue should be addressed for the stable 0.7.0 release.

Note that no version up to and including v0.7.0 supports linking based on ID.

Comment: Thanks so much for spotting the typo. That was a great help! :0)

Comment: Thank you.  Very lucky to stumble on this answer! As soon as you put something between the tags of the target link it works perfectly.